# Multiplying results of while loop in php

Tags: php, while-loop

so I have a while loop in php that I am pulling each record out of the mysql database, which works just fine, but what I want to do now is add the results of the column QTY together to get a total amount, but im not sure how to go about adding each of the results together as each time the while loop loops, it wipes the last loop.

For example if I have the following records :

```
ID  QTY   NAME
1    2    BOX1
2    54   BOX2
3    21   BOX6
```

When I echo them out in the while loop I get pretty much as they are above.
What I want to do is add the QTY to a total each time, so I can get a QTY total and have it available to use as $totalQTY .

```
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `orderid` = '$view' AND `isline` = 'no'
    SQL;
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<h2>Order Id : '.$row['orderid'].'</h2>';
    echo '<p><strong>Customer Order Number : '.$row['customerordernumber'].'</strong></p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Order Date :</strong> '.date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($row["orderdatetime"])).'</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Order Notes :</strong> '.$row['ordernotes'].'</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Label Type :</strong> '.$row['labeltype'].'</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Trolley Type :</strong> '.$row['trolleytype'].'</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Deliver By :</strong> '.$row['deliverby'].'</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Ordered Items : </strong></p>';
    }
```

Comment: Where are you performing the multiplication in this loop?

Comment: I am not, thats the question, im not sure how to multiply things in a while loop.

Comment: Example: `$qty = 1; while(...) { $qty *= $row['qty']; } echo $qty;`

Comment: may be you need an addition, not multiplication?

Comment: I sure hope that your variables are escaped. `POST order.php?view=' OR 1 = 1 --` would allow me to see all orders.

Comment: It's always a pleasure to see so much answers for such a complex question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `orderid` = '$view' AND `isline` = 'no'
SQL;
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){ die('There was an error running the query [' .$db->error . ']');}
$totalqty=0; // add this
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<h2>Order Id : '.$row['orderid'].'</h2>';
echo '<p><strong>Customer Order Number : '.$row['customerordernumber'].'</strong></p>';
echo '<p><strong>Order Date :</strong> '.date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($row["orderdatetime"])).'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Order Notes :</strong> '.$row['ordernotes'].'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Label Type :</strong> '.$row['labeltype'].'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Trolley Type :</strong> '.$row['trolleytype'].'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Deliver By :</strong> '.$row['deliverby'].'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Ordered Items : </strong></p>';
$totalqty+=intval($row['QTY??']); //your field value must be changed add this
}
```

Just add one counter variable as above :)

Comment: $totalqty+=intval($row['qty']);
}
echo '<p><strong>Number of Trees Ordered :</strong> '.$totalqty.'</p>';

This gives me total trees ordered = 0

Comment: @IainSimpson strange... How about echo $row['qty'] from your code first? It should be 0

Comment: When I copied it I missed off a closing ;

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable outside the loop, and increment it:

```
$count=0
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $count+=$row['quantity'];
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: @IainSimpson What is the actual column name for the quantity? If poss please post the result of var_dump($row); from within the loop

Answer (score 1):

Just do exactly what you wrote:

```
$totalQTY = 0
while (....) {
   //...all your code....
   $totalQTY += $row['QTY']; // you didn't give the name of the column
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and $totalQTY = 0 when the sum of all colums is 345

Comment: Well I had to guess the column name, you need to adjust that (as noted in the source)